# enviar filas de una tabla dinamica por post php

Tags: javascript, php

espero que me puedan ayudar con mi duda:
tengo esta tabla que es llenada dinamicamente atraves de Js, todo funciona perfecto pero mi duda radica en que luego de tener esta tabla visible en mi navegador como hago para caprutar todos los datos de esa tabla tal cual como estan y enviarlos por post, los quiero completos por filas todas las filas que sean generadas dinamicamente

luego de tener toda la tabla impresa en mi html como hago para pasar esos datos por filas a php?

Sé que tengo dos formas de hacerlo por ajax o por post con el name de cada uno pero teniendo en cuenta que son filas dinamicas como podría hacerlo?

Agradezco la respuesta, gracias

```
// Declaramos un arreglo donde guardar nuestros jugadores
var misJugadores = []; 

// Obtenemos nuestro elemento donde mostrar los jugadores
var jugadores = document.getElementById('jugadores');

// Creamos una clase llamada jugador con un constructor que reciba 3 párametros
class Jugador {

  constructor(nombre, edad, dinero) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.dinero = dinero;
  }

}

// Función para crear nuestro jugador
function crearJugador() {
  // Obtenemos el nombre dado por el usuario
  var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
  // Obtenemos la edad dad por el usuario y la parseamos
  var edad = parseInt(document.getElementById('edad').value)
  // Creamos nuestro jugador
  var jugador = new Jugador(nombre, edad, 0);
  // Lo añadimos a nuestro arreglo
  misJugadores.push(jugador);
  // Actualizamos nuestra tabla
  actualizarJugadores();
}

// Con esta función recorremos a todos nuestros jugadores
// en el arreglo anteriormente creado
// y los mostramos en la tabla
function actualizarJugadores() {
  // Limipamos la tabla para no repetir jugadores
  jugadores.innerHTML = ''; 
  // Recorremos nuestros jugadores
  for (var i = 0; i < misJugadores.length; i++) {
    // Añadimos nuestros jugadores a la tabla
    jugadores.innerHTML = jugadores.innerHTML +
          '<tr>' +
              '<td>' + misJugadores[i].nombre + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + misJugadores[i].edad + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + misJugadores[i].dinero + '</td>' +
          '</tr>';
  }
}
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
<form>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="Nombre" />
  <input type="text" id="edad" placeholder="Edad" />
  <input type="button" onClick="crearJugador();" value="Enviar mis datos!" />
</form>
<hr />
<h1>Mis Jugadores</h1>
<button onclick="actualizarJugadores();">Actualizar jugadores</button><br /><br />
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Nombre</td>
    <td>Edad</td>
    <td>Dinero</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="jugadores"></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba encerrando la tabla en un `<form>` y agrégale los *input* con el **type="hidden"** (escondido) en cada columna y con el name en forma de array.
Más o menos así:

```js
// Declaramos un arreglo donde guardar nuestros jugadores
var misJugadores = []; 

// Obtenemos nuestro elemento donde mostrar los jugadores
var jugadores = document.getElementById('jugadores');

// Creamos una clase llamada jugador con un constructor que reciba 3 párametros
class Jugador {

  constructor(nombre, edad, dinero) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.dinero = dinero;
  }

}

// Función para crear nuestro jugador
function crearJugador() {
  // Obtenemos el nombre dado por el usuario
  var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
  // Obtenemos la edad dad por el usuario y la parseamos
  var edad = parseInt(document.getElementById('edad').value)
  // Creamos nuestro jugador
  var jugador = new Jugador(nombre, edad, 0);
  // Lo añadimos a nuestro arreglo
  misJugadores.push(jugador);
  // Actualizamos nuestra tabla
  actualizarJugadores();
}

// Con esta función recorremos a todos nuestros jugadores
// en el arreglo anteriormente creado
// y los mostramos en la tabla
function actualizarJugadores() {
  // Limipamos la tabla para no repetir jugadores
  jugadores.innerHTML = ''; 
  // Recorremos nuestros jugadores
  for (var i = 0; i < misJugadores.length; i++) {
    // Añadimos nuestros jugadores a la tabla
    jugadores.innerHTML = jugadores.innerHTML +
          '<tr>' +
              '<td><input type="hidden" name="nombre[]" value="' + misJugadores[i].nombre + '">' + misJugadores[i].nombre + '</td>' +
              '<td><input type="hidden" name="edad[]" value="' + misJugadores[i].edad + '">' + misJugadores[i].edad + '</td>' +
              '<td><input type="hidden" name="dinero[]" value="' + misJugadores[i].dinero + '">' + misJugadores[i].dinero + '</td>' +
          '</tr>';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial;
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="nombre" placeHolder="Nombre" />
  <input type="text" id="edad" placeholder="Edad" />
  <input type="button" onClick="crearJugador();" value="Enviar mis datos!" />
</form>
<hr />
<h1>Mis Jugadores</h1>
<button onclick="actualizarJugadores();">Actualizar jugadores</button><br /><br />
<form>
<table border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Nombre</td>
    <td>Edad</td>
    <td>Dinero</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="jugadores"></tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit">
Enviar tabla completa
</button>
</form>
```

A partir de aquí has lo que quieras con el **form**, es decir, mándalo con ajax o con post hacia el script en PHP que desees, el cual puede recoger los datos más o menos así:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['nombre'])) {
  // aquí va el código
} else {
  echo "No has agregado ningún jugador!";
  die();
}
```